# Choosing a random value from an enum and then using switch to draw textures XNA c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, random, enums, xna

```
    enum rocks
    {
        uno = 1,
        dos,
        tres 

    }
```

So i declare my enum at the top,

```
rocks[] values = {rocks.uno, rocks.dos, rocks.tres};
        Random random = new Random();
        rocks randomValue = values[random.Next(values.Length)];
```

Initialise my random number generator

```
private void drawUno(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(rock1, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
    }
```

Have seperate methods to draw each rock

```
 public void drawRocks(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        switch (Rocks)
        {
            case rocks.uno:
                drawUno(spriteBatch);
                break;
            case rocks.dos:
                drawDos(spriteBatch);
                break;
            case rocks.tres:
                drawTres(spriteBatch);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

and a method to draw out whatever rock the random generates

I call back the drawRock in my main draw method but nothing comes up, what am i doing wrong?

Heres my whole class:

```
namespace PlanetDrill2
{
   public class UMA : Screen
    {


        background bgLayer1;
        background bgLayer2;
        background bgLayer3;


        Texture2D rock1;
        Texture2D rock2;
        Texture2D rock3;

        enum rocks
        {
            uno = 1,
            dos,
            tres 

        }


       rocks Rocks;


        public UMA(Game game, SpriteBatch batch, ChangeScreen changeScreen)
            : base(game, batch, changeScreen)
        {
            bgLayer1 = new background();
            bgLayer2 = new background();
            bgLayer3 = new background();

            player = new Player();

            Animation playerAnimation = new Animation();
            Texture2D playerTexture = content.Load<Texture2D>("shipAnim");
            playerAnimation.Initialize(playerTexture, Vector2.Zero, 80, 160, 5, 30, Color.White, 1f, true);

            Vector2 playerPosition = new Vector2(game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.X, game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Y
            + game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Height / 2);
            player.Initialize(playerAnimation, playerPosition);

            rock1 = content.Load<Texture2D>("rocktexture1");
            rock2 = content.Load<Texture2D>("Hardrock");
            rock3 = content.Load<Texture2D>("rarerock");

            bgLayer1.Initialize(content, "scrollingrocks", game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, -10);
            bgLayer2.Initialize(content, "scrollingrocks2", game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, -6);
            bgLayer3.Initialize(content, "scrollingrocks3", game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, -4);

            float playerMoveSpeed;


            playerMoveSpeed = 8.0f;


            rocks[] values = {rocks.uno, rocks.dos, rocks.tres};
            Random random = new Random();
            rocks randomValue = values[random.Next(values.Length)];


        }





        private void drawUno(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(rock1, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
        }

        private void drawDos(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(rock2, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
        }

        private void drawTres(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(rock3, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
        }



        public void drawRocks(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {

            switch (Rocks)
            {
                case rocks.uno:
                    drawUno(spriteBatch);
                    break;
                case rocks.dos:
                    drawDos(spriteBatch);
                    break;
                case rocks.tres:
                    drawTres(spriteBatch);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }




        private void UpdatePlayer(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            player.Update(gameTime);

            TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.FreeDrag;

            float positionChange = 0;
            float oldPosition = 0;
            while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
            {
                GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();

                if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.FreeDrag)
                {
                    float newposition = gesture.Position.X;
                    if (oldPosition != 0)
                    {


                        positionChange = newposition - oldPosition;
                        player.Position.X += positionChange;
                    }
                    oldPosition = newposition;

                }

            }



            // Make sure that the player does not go out of bounds
            player.Position.X = MathHelper.Clamp(player.Position.X, 0, game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - player.Width);
            player.Position.Y = MathHelper.Clamp(player.Position.Y, 0, game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - player.Height);



        }



        protected override void SetupInputs()
        {
            base.SetupInputs();
        }

        public override void Activate()
        {
            base.Activate();
        }

        protected override void LoadScreenContent(ContentManager content)
        {
            base.LoadScreenContent(content);
        }

        protected override void UpdateScreen(GameTime gameTime, DisplayOrientation screenOrientation)
        {
            bgLayer1.Update();
            bgLayer2.Update();
            bgLayer3.Update();
            UpdatePlayer(gameTime);

            base.UpdateScreen(gameTime, screenOrientation);
        }

        protected override void DrawScreen(SpriteBatch batch, DisplayOrientation screenOrientation)
        {
            bgLayer3.Draw(batch);
            bgLayer2.Draw(batch);
            bgLayer1.Draw(batch);

            player.Draw(batch);
            drawRocks(batch);

            base.DrawScreen(batch, screenOrientation);
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: rock r = (rock)Enum.ToObject(typeof(rock),randomizer.Next(0,Enum.GetValues(typeof(rock)).Length));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot something. You're picking a random rock:

```
rocks randomValue = values[random.Next(values.Length)];
```

Then you don't use randomValue at all. Instead you're using `Rocks` in your switch statement:

```
switch (Rocks)
{
    case rocks.uno:
        drawUno(spriteBatch);
        break;
    case rocks.dos:
        drawDos(spriteBatch);
        break;
    case rocks.tres:
        drawTres(spriteBatch);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

So either use `randomValue` in your switch, or assign the random value to your `Rocks` property.

Comment: I thought what i was doing was determining the switch by putting them in random generator? 
:

Comment: 'rocks[] values = {rocks.uno, rocks.dos, rocks.tres};' ?

Comment: Yes. Then you're picking a rock from `values`. Then you're storing that rock in `randomValue`. Then you're not doing anything with `randomValue`.

Comment: Just replace `rocks randomValue = values[random.Next(values.Length)];` by `Rocks = values[random.Next(values.Length)];` and it should work.

Comment: That did work, thank you dude, so i guess all this code does is choose one random rock and it never changes? How do i get it to keep generating more? 

Should i create another method that deals with what happens with the current rock and another to keep generating more?

Comment: You can take the three lines starting at `rocks[] values = {rocks.uno, rocks.dos, rocks.tres};` and move them at the beginning of the `drawRocks` method to pick a new random rock each time.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, cheers bud for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing any Begin and End calls on the SpriteBatch. These are needed for things to display on screen. Look at the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195108.aspx). It clearly mentions this.

Comment: Sorry i need to explain further, the spritebatch begin and end calls are being called in another class, this is merely just one of the screens.